# Trouble with Cork authentication for Bottle app: TypeError("'NoneType' object does not support item assignment",)

Tags: python, authentication, wsgi, bottle

I'm having some trouble implementing the Cork library with a Bottle app. I've tried setting up the example app, and I made some minor modifications to get it to run in an WSGI container. The main change is that I changed this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

to this:

```
application = default_app()
```

When I authenticate with the admin user, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path_to_app/lib/python2.7/bottle-0.11.4-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 763, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/path_to_app/lib/python2.7/bottle-0.11.4-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 1572, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/path_to_app/cork-example/simple_webapp.py", line 47, in login
    aaa.login(username, password, success_redirect='/', fail_redirect='/login')
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cork/cork.py", line 209, in login
    self._setup_cookie(username)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cork/cork.py", line 610, in _setup_cookie
    session['username'] = username
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

When I attempt to view the main page, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path_to_app/lib/python2.7/bottle-0.11.4-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 763, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/path_to_app/lib/python2.7/bottle-0.11.4-py2.7.egg/bottle.py", line 1572, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/path_to_app/cork-example/simple_webapp.py", line 90, in index
    aaa.require(fail_redirect='/login')
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cork/cork.py", line 267, in require
    cu = self.current_user
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cork/cork.py", line 417, in current_user
    username = session.get('username', None)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Is there a newbie mistake I might be making? Or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a newbie mistake. The Bottle documentation says that if you want to use Bottle with mod_wsgi, toward the end of the file, you should use this:

```
application = default_app()
```

After getting a better understanding of how this all works, I realized I was sending the wrong application object to mod_wsgi. Instead, I should have used this:

```
application = app #app was defined earlier in the example application
```